# How to use conditional tags to switch this style sheets?

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, conditional-statements

My site works fine but I want to slightly change my if else conditions as per my new requirement.
Right now I think it's not about `wordpress` but it's about how to change some `PHP conditional tags`.
So I am asking here.

My previous requirements were :

1. If the site is loaded on mobile site I have to show a button and
   when it's clicked the site should enqueue a style sheet called
   responsive.css
2. When the site is (in mobile) responsive another button should be
   shown to switch to default style.css when the button is clicked.

I put following buttons:

```
<div class="cr-athavan-lang-image">
    <a href="?site=mobile" class="mobile_site" id="mobile_site"><img src="file/path/to/img" alt="switch to mobile site"></a>
    <a href="?site=desktop" class="desktop_site"><img src="file/path/to/img" alt="switch to desktop site"></a>  
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
.desktop_site { display: none; }  /* Hiding switch to desktop site button if the site is loaded on desktop */
```

**responsive.css**

```
.desktop_site { display: block; margin-top: 5px; } /* bring back switch to desktop site button if the site is loaded on mobile */
```

And my `functions.php`

```
<?php
if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) { // to hide mobile switching button on desktop site 
    function print_inline_script_hide_site_switch() {                   
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">     
            jQuery('.mobile_site').hide();                                              
        </script>
        <?php                 
    }
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'print_inline_script_hide_site_switch' );
}
    else {              
        add_action('init', 'is_it_mobile_or_desktop', 1);
        function is_it_mobile_or_desktop(){
            if (isset($_GET['site']) && in_array($_GET['site'], array('mobile', 'desktop'))){
                setcookie( 'site', $_GET['site'], time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
            }
        }

        add_action('init', 'who_am_i', 2);
        function who_am_i(){

            $site = isset($_GET['site']) && in_array($_GET['site'], array('mobile', 'desktop')) ?  $_GET['site'] : 
                    (isset($_COOKIE['site']) && in_array($_COOKIE['site'], array('mobile', 'desktop'))  ? $_COOKIE['site'] : 'default_css');

            if ($site == 'mobile'){
                function responsive_css(){
                    wp_enqueue_style(
                        'wpa_custom',
                        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css'
                    );
                }
                add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'responsive_css', 999 );

                function print_my_inline_script() {                 
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    /*My inline scripts*/                                               
                    </script>
                    <?php                 
                }
                add_action( 'wp_footer', 'print_my_inline_script' );

            } 
            else {
                function default_css(){
                    wp_enqueue_style(
                        'default_css',
                        get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'
                    );
                }
                add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'default_css', 999 );
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This is how I achieved my old requirements and work fine. No any issue in 1st & 2nd requirements

Now I have updated requirements:

1. By default a non-responsive site should be loaded if the user from
   desktop
2. By default a responsive site should be loaded if the user from
   mobile
3. If the user clicks a desktop switching button from mobile
   (responsive) site, the non-responsive site should be loaded in the
   mobile.
4. If the user clicks a mobile switching button from mobile
   (non-responsive) site, the responsive site should be loaded.

**In summary:**

1. If the site is loaded on mobile it should enqueue the style sheet
   `style.css` and should show the `button desktop_site`
2. If the user clicks the `button desktop_site` then it should enqueue
   `responsive.css` and should show the `button mobile_site`
3. If the user clicks `mobile_site button` again it should enqueue
   `style.css`and should show the `button desktop_site`

I think it almost just `if else condition changes` but I could not solve.

Suggestions and solutions please....

Comment: It seems you ask your visitor to click a button so CSS hide or show elements in order to make them "responsive". Why don't you use media queries ?

Comment: That's what I suggested to my clients on the beginning. But still they want a non responsive version of the site when the users visit from desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is related to one of your wordpress exchange question: wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193813/how-to-switch-css-files-according-to-devices-and-button-click/

And yes as you assumed the solution is in `if` statement :

Change

```
if (($site == 'desktop'){ // code line }
```

TO

```
if (($site == 'desktop') && (wp_is_mobile())) { // code line }
```

Comment: Thanks.. that works.. rather down voting you understood the requirement..  Clients are Right even they are Wrong.. what to do.. That's why I needed this....